# Python BeautifulSoup scrape Yahoo Finance value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the 'Full Time Employees' value of 110,000 from the Yahoo finance website.

The URL is: `http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL`

I have tried using Beautiful soup, but I can't find the value on the page.  When I look in the DOM explorer in IE, I can see it.  It has a  tag with a parent tag  which has a parent

which has a parent .  The actual value is in a custom class of `data-react-id`.

code I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html=`http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL`
r = requests.get(html).content
soup = bs(r)
```

Not sure where to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the "requests" related part - *the page you download with `requests` is not the same as you see in the browser*. Browser executed all of the javascript, made multiple asynchronous requests needed to load this page. And, this particular page is quite *dynamic* itself. There is a lot happening on the "client-side".

What you can do is to load this page in a real browser automated by [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL")

# wait for the Full Time Employees to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
employees = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Full Time Employees']/following-sibling::strong")))
print(employees.text)

driver.close()
```

Prints `110,000`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  I installed selenium successfully, but unable to get the Chrome Driver to work.

Comment: This solution seems to be a bit of a hack.  Is there a way to just do this 'directly', or do we need to 'hack' this by tricking that we are using Chrome?

Comment: @clg4 you can go with firefox or phantomjs or safari or ... as well. E.g. for firefox: `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`.

Comment: how about IE?  By the way, plus 1 but can't accept this yet.  Would like to see if a direct method...

Comment: @clg4 or IE, of course. Though, it can be more trickier to set up. I think the easiest to starts with is Firefox.

Comment: got this to work on IE.  Thanks!  PS Still would love a way to do this without having it open the browser etc...  Accepted Solution but let me know if there might be another way...

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to download financial data, or any kind of data, from the web. The script below downloads stock prices and saves everything to a CSV file.

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

Output_File = open('C:/Users/your_path/Historical_Prices.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```

The script below will download multiple stock tickers into one folder.

```
import urllib
import re
import json

symbolslist = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/tickers.txt").read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

for symbol in symbolslist:
    myfile = open("C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "w+")
    myfile.close()

    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/"+ symbol+ ":US")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    datapoints = data["data_values"]

    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "a")
    for point in datapoints:
        myfile.write(str(symbol+","+str(point[0])+","+str(point[1])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

Finally...this will download prices for multiple stock tickers...

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/symbols/amex.txt")
symbollist = symbolfile.read()

newsymbolslist = symbollist.split("\n")

i=0
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + newsymbolslist[i] + "&ql=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + newsymbolslist[i] + '">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "the price of ", newsymbolslist[i] , "is", price[0]
    i+=1

# Make sure you place the 'amex.txt' file in 'C:\Python27\'
```

I wrote a book about these kinds of things, and lots of other stuff. You can find it using the URL below.

[https://www.amazon.com/Automating-Business-Processes-Reducing-Increasing-ebook/dp/B01DJJKVZC/ref=sr_1_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DJJKVZC)?