# Python: finding elements of a webpage to scrape in python when page content is loaded using Java script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape content of a page.
Let's say this is the page:
http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL

I know I need to use `Selenium` to get the data I want.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197977/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-yahoo-finance-value) example from Stackoverflow that shows how to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL")

# wait for the Full Time Employees to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
employees = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Full Time Employees']/following-sibling::strong")))
print(employees.text)

driver.close()
```

My question is this:
In the above example to find **Full Time Employees** the code that has been used is:

```
employees = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Full Time Employees']/following-sibling::strong")))
```

How the author has found that s/he needs to use:

```
"//span[. = 'Full Time Employees']/following-sibling::strong"
```

To find the number of employees.

For my example page: http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL how can I find for example **Trailing P/E**?

Comment: that's an `XPATH` selector, you can learn more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp). You can also use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but how to find the XPATH?

Comment: you'll have to check the html structure you want to parse and come up with a way to uniquely search the data you want. the link has a lot of tutorials

Comment: Thanks again. The question is how to find the html that page returns on the first place? I cannot look at the page source.

Comment: In osx and if you are using Chrome, you can see it with `option + cmd + U`. Or `right click -> Inspect` (aka developer tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please tell me the steps you took to find this? I do right click and choose Inspect, but then what shall I do?

A picture is worth of thousand words.

[image]
In web dev. tools (F12) you do the following steps:

1. Choose *Elements* tab
2. Press *Element Selector* button
3. With that button pressed you click an element in the main browser window.
4. In the DOM-elements window you *right-click that highlighted element*.
5. The context menu gets transpired and you choose *Copy*.
6. Choose *Copy XPath* in a sub menu. Now you have that element xpath in a console buffer.

### NOTE!

The browser makes/composes an element xpath based on its own algorithm. It **might not be** the way you think or the way that fits to your code. So, you have to understand xpath in nature, be [acquainted with it](https://webscraping.pro/example-xpath/).

See what xpath the Chrome browser has issued for *Trailing P/E*:

> //*[@id="main-0-Quote-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/section/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span

Comment: That is a fantastic answer, very clear and worked for me, thank you so much for spending the time, I accepted it and upvoted it.

Comment: @TJ1, I'm glad that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
'//h3[contains(., "Valuation Measures")]/following-sibling::div[1]//tr[3]'
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me the steps you took to find this? I do right click and choose `Inspect`, but then what shall I do?

Comment: This isn't something you "find". You'll have to come up with a unique way to find the node you need according to the html structure you are trying to parse

Comment: I undrestand, but where did you look to find `//h3[contains(., "Valuation Measures")]/following-sibling::div[1]//tr[3]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have the answer for all your confusions.

It will be better to look on some `xpath` tutorials and do practice from yourself, then you will be able to decide what you have to use .
There are so many site. You can start [Here](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium) or [Here](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Now come to your Query -

Suppose I am using following `xpath` to locate the element

```
//h3/span[text()='Financial Highlights']/../preceding-sibling::div//tr[3]/td/span
```

1. Your requirement to find **Trailing P/E** in your page, definatly you will look unique xpath which won't change. If you try to find this using `firepath` it shows some lengthy `xpath`
2. Now you will check alternative and find another element (may be sibling, child or ancestor of your element) based on that you can to locate your element

   - in My case, first will find the **Financial Highlights** text which I will be able to find using `//h3/span[text()='Financial Highlights']`
   - Now I move its parent tag which is `h3` and I will do this using `/..`
   - I have **Trailing P/E** element in just above the current node so move on just above node using `/preceding-sibling::div`
   - And finally find your element in that `<div>` like -`//tr[3]/td/span`

See the screens as well -

**Step 1 :**
[image]

**Step 2 :**
[image]

**Step 3 :**
[image]

**Step 4 :**
[image]